# Direction and Size of Placeholder in SmartGWT Mobile

Tags: gwt, smartgwt, mobile-application, gxt

[image: place holder]

I have a Text Item added to a dynamic form in smart GWT mobile (as shown in the image). On the right there is the place holder, when I start typing it starts from far end. I want it to start typing from the left that is after title.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the text alignment to LEFT.
In non-mobile version text alignment can be changed using `textItem.setTextAlign(Alignment.LEFT);`

Also, see if anything can be done by changing length, how hints are displayed, how title is displayed, etc. using available API methods.

I have not used SmartGWT mobile, so this might not solve the problem.

What I feel is, mobile input fields are designed to optimize screen space on mobile devices, by pushing title and input toward left and right side of the screen, putting any left over space in the middle.

When testing in a browser or other simulator it would look like lot of space in between label and input, but when used in a mobile device, it might look quite alright.